# Unable to build marlin in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been banging my head against a brick wall trying to find out a solution to this problem. So following some tutorials as I am now pretty new to visual studio and platformio. Followed the instruction word for word, installing vs code, platformio and importing my arduino project. I should add everything from visual studio, platformio and marlin are fresh downloads without any alteration.

As suggested in the tutorial I selected the environment which is the mega2560 for the ramps board and pressed build. This is what came out.

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
'CC' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CalledProcessError: Command 'CC -D__MARLIN_FIRMWARE__ -w -dM -E -x c++ buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/common-dependencies.h' returned non-zero exit status 1.:

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\penv\lib\site-packages\platformio\builder\main.py", line 168:env.SConscript(item, exports="env")

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.0.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 598:return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.0.1\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 287:exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)

File "C:\Users\JR\Documents\Marlin-2.0.6.1VS\Marlin-2.0.6.1\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 280:apply_features_config()

File "C:\Users\JR\Documents\Marlin-2.0.6.1VS\Marlin-2.0.6.1\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 112:if not env.MarlinFeatureIsEnabled(feature):

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.0.1\SCons\Environment.py", line 219:return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JR\Documents\Marlin-2.0.6.1VS\Marlin-2.0.6.1\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 256:load_marlin_features()

File "C:\Users\JR\Documents\Marlin-2.0.6.1VS\Marlin-2.0.6.1\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 244:define_list = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).splitlines()

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411:**kwargs).stdout

File "C:\Users\JR.platformio\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 512:output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
================================================================ [FAILED] Took 0.79 seconds ================================================================

Environment    Status    Duration

---

mega2560       FAILED    00:00:00.786

Could someone enlighten me to how to fix this because I have hunted high and low on forums and google with little to no answer.